# how to get specific value from db and show result in view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have problem to show my query result in my view, i user codeigniter with mvc structure, in model my code its look like this,

```
<?php
class Model_Kabalitbang extends CI_Model{

    public function getPaguAnggaran(){
        $query  = "SELECT pagu_anggaran_program_modalutama FROM program_modal_utama WHERE id_program_modalutama = '3'
                  ";
        return $this->db->query($query);      
    }
}
```

and in my controller i call my model like this

```
<?php
class Kabalitbang extends CI_Controller{
  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') !== TRUE){
      redirect('login');
    }

    $this->load->model('Model_Kabalitbang');
  }

  function index(){
    //Allowing akses to kabalitbang only
    if($this->session->userdata('level')==='2'){
      // Jumlah PAGU
        $pagu            = $this->Model_Kabalitbang->getPaguAnggaran();
        $paguanggaran    = $pagu->num_rows();

        $data = array(
            'jml_pagu'      => $paguanggaran,
        );
      $this->load->view('kabalitbang/dashboard_view', $data);
    }else{
        echo "Access Denied";
    }

  }

}
```

but when i call in view `<?=$jml_pagu ?>` this show just 1, but the value form field in my query is 24392
[image: this is my result query]

how to make my code run?

Comment: can you confirm that running the `SELECT pagu_anggaran_program_modalutama FROM program_modal_utama WHERE id_program_modalutama = '3'` query returns `24392` rows?

Comment: yes when i try run my query, the result is 243929203000

Comment: @HastaDhana i already updated my question, thank you for help me

Answer (score 1):

Your query is already return a row containing a number, so you just need to display the row, not counting the row again :

```php
        $pagu            = $this->Model_Kabalitbang->getPaguAnggaran();
        $paguanggaran    = $pagu->row_array();

        $data = array(
            'jml_pagu'      => $paguanggaran['pagu_anggaran_program_modalutama'],
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

use this...

```
$this->db->where('id_program_modalutama ',3);
$result['data']=$this->db->get('Table Name')->result();
$this->load->view('kabalitbang/dashboard_view', $result);
```

now use loop  on $data in your view...
Example :-

```
foreach($data as $allData)
{
print_r($allData);
}
```